# Import XML with BCP into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, import, bcp

This code not import the whole xml file contents, but only a part.

```
bcp s1.dbo.table_test in myfile.xml -c -T -S localhost\sqlexpress
```

My file is a large file, around 100 MB and my table has the xml column

How to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Where are you storing this (data type)? How are you detecting, that there is *only a part*? Might be, that everything is OK, but you see a truncated output...

Comment: table has the xml column @Shnugo

Comment: That's waht I thought... If the XML was read partially it was not valid (at least the end closing tag was missing) and you would not be able to store this in a XML column. So: How are you testing the result?

Comment: how can I see if a loaded all xml file contents@Shnugo

Comment: select * from my table @Shnugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I assume, that your XML was read completely. Storing data within an XML column is impossible, if the XML is not valid...

You might try:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(YourXMLColumn) FROM YourTable
```

and see the used bytes (attention: its `unicode`, two bytes per char).

Or Try

```
SELECT LEN(CAST(YourXML AS VARCHAR(MAX))) FROM YourTable
```

returns the count of characters

Or

- right click into your query
- go to the options
- find the options for the data grid
- set the XML size to unlimited

Hope this helps

Comment: is not easy :(  SELECT DATALENGTH(YourXMLColumn) FROM YourTable  show: 176830766 @Shnugo

Comment: You can help me figure out if it is 100 MB ?Shnugo

Comment: @J.si, this number is the count of bytes used. 176.830.766 Bytes is about 180MB. If your XML is roughly this size (or the half of this, ~90MB), it looks quite well...

Comment: @J.si some own effort would help :-) It took me seconds to find this: http://www.matisse.net/bitcalc/?input_amount=176830766&input_units=bytes&notation=legacy

Comment: if I see the properties of the file on the desktop my file is 111 MB (116.524.437 byte) @Shanugo

Comment: Why they're different ? :(

Comment: @J.si While storing the XML SQL Server will re-structure the content. Things like `<SomeElement></SomeElement>` might become `<SomeElement/>` and so on. But ~180MB **does not sound like 'not completed'** :-) Did you try my hint with the query options?

Comment: no I'm using the prompt , I can't right click into my query

Comment: You could try to write the stored data back into a file... But - to be honest - I think this is OK... Haven't you got a `SQL Server Management Studio` to check this properly? Anyway, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter, if this could solve your issue... Thx

Comment: I do not have SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I'm not sure that the command (bcp s1.dbo.table_test in myfile.xml -c -T -S localhost\sqlexpress)is right @Shnugo

Comment: It is rather unusual to work with SQL Server without SSMS... which version are you running? If your command is correct? Well there is 180MB data which wasn't there before and it is stored in an XML column which would not accept invalid XML (and truncated XML is - for sure! - not valid). if you want to continue your work, you should start to use proper tools...

Comment: sql server Express 2014

Comment: @J.si together with the Express version you get the SSMS Express too. You should have it already...

Comment: (and truncated XML is - for sure! - not valid) .. I did not think about it tahnk you

Comment: @J.si Is your issue solved now? If yes, please tick the acceptance check, thx

Comment: I think it has loaded all the content

Comment: the time of clock is the time of loaded?  they are the same thing? @Shnugo

Comment: @J.si Sorry, don't understand that... Which time of which clock and where is a *time of loaded*?

Comment: I want to know the xml file loading time .
and bcp show the time of clock @Shnugo

Comment: This is a new question...New question pull the most attraction ... One issue, one question is a good principle, as it makes it easier to find answers if you have some troubles which are solved already... thx